# Laravel process component Security issue?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, security, components

I have question , is there is any security issue with this way of code? in  Laravel Symfony component?

```
        $process = new Process('youtube-dl -j '.request('user_input');
        $process->run();
        $output = $process->getOutput();
```

I saw some examples in the documentation but it was like `ls -lsa` without user  input. Is it possible to inject malicious code from users?

Any help before I apply this method please?

Answer (score 2):

It is 100% not safe.

I have no idea about Symfony but from first impression, it is not safe.

Firstly, you are injecting the input into your command string, that means you are passing one parameter as a string.

How can the process understand which one is your user's inputs?

I suggest that you read the documentation again. You may find a way to pass user input as an additional parameter.

If you find that, I think you will be safe.